# plot graph in R from matrix

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I have generated `matrix 1000x180` and I am trying to `plot it on the same graph by rows` in the following way:

```
plot(1:180, matrix[1,], type = "l")
plot(1:180, matrix[2,], type = "l")
.................. and etc.
```

Is there any way to plot these subplots with legend and different colors using matrix as input in plot function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a fast visualisation you can use `matplot`:

```
matplot(t(matrix(runif(10*180),ncol=180)),type='l',lty=1) ## 10x180 matrix
```

[image]

But I don't think you can extract a lot of information from a plot of 1000*180. You should group your data to get better visualization.

Comment: In general  I agree.  The OP may be hoping to show that all rows fall within some specified range, but as you say he'd be better off plotting, e.g., the median, +/-sigma, +/-3*sigma lines.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft exactly what I mean. In general when it is difficult to read the legend(imagine the legend of 1000*180) of a plot, we should rethink what we want to do.

Comment: you may want to add `lty=1` to get continuous line. It helps with the visualization.